# Magento 2: Using Root Level "mini-applications" Applications When Serving Files from `pub`

Tags: magento2, component-manager

Magento 2 ships with an `index.php` and `.htaccess` file in the `pub` folder

```
pub/index.php
```

This is good, as it allows Apache or nginx to be configured with a web root that's more secure.

However, Magento 2 also ships with an `index.php` file in the root project folder.  Per previous comments from internal product owners, this is to work with web hosts that don't allow users to set a different web root.

Additionally, Magento 2 also ships with a few "mini-applications" that live off the root folder.

```
./setup/index.php
./update/index.php
```

One is the GUI installer (`setup`). The other is something called that component manager (`update`), an application that's presumed to be part of Magento 2 marketplace.

Is it possible to run Magento 2 using the more secure `pub` mode and still access these mini applications?

Or do you need to run Magento in the less secure "root index.php"  mode to access them?

Answer (score 2):

On Nginx *(using the vhost sample configuration file included in the magento distribution)* pointing the server root to `pub` folder I have access to `setup/index.php` by this url:

> http://{magento_base_url}/setup

I guess the magic occurs here:

> Nginx Vhost File

```
...
location /setup {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}
...
```

I haven't tried `/update` yet but there is a similar configuration in the nginx vhost file.

Full nginx vhots file [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/nginx.conf.sample).

I guess that for apache users would be "nice to have" a vhost configuration sample like the nginx one, to avoid the `.htaccess` rewrites.

Comment: +1 Good to know -- do the applications behave correctly?  i.e. Are file paths and URLs are generated correctly when running the application out of those folders?

Comment: Mmh I can't confirm that, actually the install setup works perfect but i have several errors when I try to update (from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2) I can't pass the readyness check, that errors could be related to paths, but i didn't checked well yet.

Answer (score 1):

shorter answer is:
you define master root folder location:

and then you can manipulate with it, per `server{}`:

```
server { 
##################################
## Set Magento root folder
set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
##################################
## Set main public directory /pub
root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
##################################
```

per `location{}`, etc:

```
location ~ ^/(setup|update) {
## Set main setup directory /
root $MAGE_ROOT;
##################################
```

about apps behavior: paths and locations translated to php-fpm, so it is important how your backed/php is configured.

for Apache 2.4+ server the same logic can be configured using mod_macro:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html

```
<Macro DocRoot ${docroot}>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/${docroot}/htdocs"
</Macro>
```

Comment: That's good for nginx, but what about apache?

Comment: Please see answer updated

Comment: and have these mini-application been vetted to work with these configurations?  Will paths, URLs, and asset URLs be correctly generated?

Comment: you have to try :) but i guess as long as you have all correctly configured it will work

Comment: Re: I have to try -- I'm not spending a few days doing free QA work for Magento Inc. :)